# Scrolling problems with kendo-ui Autocomplete in embedded mode (without iframes)

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I'm currently altering a website which was devided into iframes to now being embedded (with AngularJS), without any iframes.

There is a big problem with this: I had a Kendo UI auto-complete drop-down element for selecting locations. The behavior with iframe and embedded is totally different concerning scrolling in the area around/beneath the auto-complete drop-down.

Old app: the site (iframe) around scrolled and the drop-down still was visible and moved with the rest of the site until you selected an item.
New app: the drop-down box closes immediately and  you have to retype some input to get it open again. Unacceptable usability!

How do I get an auto-complete drop-down (doesn't have to be Kendo if not possible) which does have the OLD scrolling behavior in embedded mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a **workaround** which works fine for me:

In the directive html, I added a callback for the event `k-close`. In this callback in the controller I **prevented the default behavior of close event** (of course under specific conditions) with the following code in the controller:

```
$scope.closeCallback= function (e) {
     if (someConditionForWhichDropdownShouldntBeClosed) {
          e.preventDefault();
     }
};
```

and here's the HTML of the directive:

```
<input
    ng-model="model"        
    kendo-auto-complete="source"
    k-data-source="locationDataSource"
    k-select="selectLocation"
    k-close="closeCallback">
```

In my case, I prevented the Dropdown being closed as long as no item was selected.

For this I added a new boolean scope variable which was false by default, was set true if dropdown opened:

```
$scope.locationDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "json",
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
             $scope.keepKendoDropdownOpen = true;
             someOtherFuncionalityAfterSelectingAnItem();
        }
     }
});
```

and set false again after selecting (in the callback of the directive's `k-select`).

Would be nice to also watch if the user presses ESC or something, but until now it's okay enough.

Please feel free to make my solution better or post other solutions! :-)